# How to change the repository path gradle plugins get published to?

Tags: maven, gradle, plugins, artifactory, publish

I am new to using Gradle, but,
I currently have Gradle set up to publish all the custom plugins I have made into a repository in Artifactory. Unfortunately, they publish nested a layer deeper than I would like. The problem I am having is that the plugins are getting published into Artifactory like:

```
gradleplugins-mvn-common
 -> ca
    -> pluginproj
       -> gradle
          -> plugin1
             -> ca.pluginproj.gradle.plugin1.gradle.plugin1.gradle.plugin
                ->plugin info (version, XML, sha, etc.)
```

Artifactory is showing me the Repository url as

> gradleplugins-mvn-common/ca/pluginproj/gradle/plugin1/ca.pluginproj.gradle.plugin1.gradle.plugin1.gradle.plugin/

Instead, I would like to get them to look like this:

```
gradleplugins-mvn-common
 -> ca
    -> pluginproj
       -> gradle
          -> plugin1
                ->plugin info (version, XML, sha, etc.)
```

with the url being:

> gradleplugins-mvn-common/ca/pluginproj/gradle/plugin1/

***build.gradle***

```
group = 'ca.pluginproj.gradle'

gradlePlugin{
    plugins {
         Plugin1 {
             id = project.group + ".Plugin1"
             implementationClass = 'ca.pluginproj.gradle.plugins.Plugin1'
         }
         Plugin2 {
             id = project.group + ".Plugin2"
             implementationClass = 'ca.pluginproj.gradle.plugins.Plugin2'
         }
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name "PLUGINS_COMMON"
            url "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/gradleplugins-mvn-common/"
            allowInsecureProtocol
            credentials {
                username ******
                password ******
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to go about making this change would be greatly appreciated!